# Compile error - reading in from file

Tags: c, string, compilation, scanf

I have declared a char array like so...

```
char workingString[1032]
```

I am reading into this array with fscanf like so...

```
fscanf(ifp, " %s", &workingString);
```

I get this compile error for this particular line of code where I use fscanf

```
warning; format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[1032]' [W-format]
```

I do not understand what the error is telling and thus I don't know where to begin to correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're taking the address of the array, which means the resulting value has type "pointer to array of 1032 character", but `fscanf()` needs a plain "pointer to character". The *value* of the two pointers would be the same, but the type differs.

Thus, all you need is to drop the `&` operator since the name of the array decays to a pointer to the first element:

```
fscanf(ifp, " %s", workingString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
fscanf(ifp, " %s", workingString);
```

You should never use `&`  for arrays in a `scanf()` or related functions.